# google maps does not shown in android, but does shown in chrome (phonegap)

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, cordova, phonegap

im using phonegap to build my app and when im trying to open the app and sea at the main page the map, i get grey cover instead of the map in android. 
also when i open it in chrome i can sea the map.

code attached :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height= device-height, initial-scale=1">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainCSS.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/sideAndUpperMenuCSS.css">
    <link href='http://serve.fontsproject.com/css?family=Felix007:400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="js/mainScript.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sideAndUpperMenuScript.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
</div>
<div id="floating-panel">
    <button class="icon" id="submit"></button>
    <input type="text" align="right" id="address" placeholder="חיפוש כתובת" />
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<span id="requestPointZone">
     <button class="btn btn-info btn-block bigButton" onclick="changeButtons()" id="choiceList">הזמן נקודת מכירה</button>
</span>
<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyADlk_CtGRjQOGs3fk8NjG9yVQwj4xPxnI&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

js file :

```
function geocodeAddress(resultsMap, geocoder) {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            resultsMap.setZoom(15);
            resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        } 
    });
}


function onSuccess(position) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: {lat: position.coords.latitude , lng: position.coords.longitude},
        mapTypeControl: false
    });
    initPage(map);  
}

function onError(error) {
    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: {lat: 32.080633 , lng: 34.789022},
        mapTypeControl: false
    });
    initPage(map);  
}

function initPage(map){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/APPserver/clientServlet",
        data: {requestType :"mainMarkers"},
        success: function(location) {
            for(var i=0; i<location.length; i++) {
                var coords = location[i].split("-");
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    id: location[i],
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    if (this.getAnimation() != null) {
                        this.setAnimation(null);
                    } else {
                        this.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                    }
                    marker = this.id;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        window.location.href = "salePoint.html"+ "?id=" + marker;
                    }, 900)
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(lo){   console.log("error" + lo.message);}
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    );
}


function initMap() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}
```

also the config.xml file contains this lines :

```
 </platform>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
    </feature>
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="LSApplicationQueriesSchemes">
            <array>
                <string>waze</string>
            </array>
        </config-file>
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <gap:plugin name="phonegap-facebook-plugin" version="0.12.0">
        <param name="APP_ID" value="1901343470147655" />
        <param name="APP_NAME" value="FarmobileApp" />
    </gap:plugin>
    <access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes"/>
```

i added this line :

as i saw at the log file of phonegap, but still same problem.

any ideas ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

ok the problem was this line :
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

once i put it under comment it worked.